# Facing performance issue converting raw data from byte array of http request

Tags: java, performance, httprequest, cpu-usage

We are using below code to extract raw data from http request and its taking quite a long time. Also CPU utilization peeks during this time. Request header has an XML with close to 4000-5000 characters. Is there any way we can re-write below code to save on time and utilization?

```
private byte[] getRequestBytes(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    byte[] requestBytes = null;
    byte[] streamBytes = new byte[1];
    InputStream stream = request.getInputStream();
    int length = 0;
    ByteArrayOutputStream arrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while((length = stream.read(streamBytes,0,1)) != -1) {
        arrayOutputStream.write(streamBytes);
    }
    requestBytes = arrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    return requestBytes;
}
```

Java version is 1.7u45

Comment: why not increase your buffer size `byte[] streamBytes = new byte[1];`?

Comment: A 1-byte buffer? How about using a larger buffer? E.g. 1024 or 4096.

Comment: What is the purpose of `requestBytes`? Why initialize to `null`?

Comment: Resource leak: `stream` never closed!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some issues with the code :

1. `byte[] streamBytes = new byte[1];` this buffer is too small use something like 4096.
2. you are not closing your stream ,which may lead to resource leak.
3. `stream.read(streamBytes,0,1)` you are reading only on one `byte` per  loop execution , which leads to poor performance.
4. use of `length` variable is redundant you could just do `stream.read(streamBytes,0,1) != -1`

Comment: Thanks.. But the size of input is variable and sometime they may not have any input. That is why reading one byte at a time. Length we can remove and see. requestBytes are used to return calling unit and then do further processing.

Comment: Is there any better way to rewrite the above code.. Using some other option?

Comment: @shr That's not a valid reason not to read/write more than a byte at a time.